# Restore Telegram Profile From Backup

Tags: telegram

I can't access the telephone number that is connected to my telegram account.  However, I have a backup of my snap telegram-desktop files from my previous Ubuntu installation (16.04).  I tried to install telegram on my current system and copy the previous snap telegram-desktop files to recover my account via ubuntu 18.04 using `'sudo mv /path/from/backup/telegram-dekstop /snap/'`, however the restored files seem to be completely ignored my current telegram installation. When I open telegram I get a new user welcome rather than my previous account.

Any suggestions on how I can properly restore my snap telegram account files?

Are there other telegram-desktop config files somewhere that I have not copied?

The obvious thought being that if I can recover my ubuntu profile, then perhaps I can update my phone number that way.